# Tensorflow Serving Compiling Failure For CPU AVX AVX2

Tags: tensorflow-serving, tfx

I use the method in the tfx official document to compile the tfx devel in docker file. The OS is MacOS, intel CPU.

here is the docker build code for it

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=$1
TAG=$2

TF_SERVING_VERSION_GIT_BRANCH="2.4.1"

git clone --branch="${TF_SERVING_VERSION_GIT_BRANCH}" https://github.com/tensorflow/serving

TF_SERVING_BUILD_OPTIONS="--copt=-mavx --local_ram_resources=4096"

cd serving && \
  docker build --pull -t $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel:$TAG \
  --build-arg TF_SERVING_VERSION_GIT_BRANCH="${TF_SERVING_VERSION_GIT_BRANCH}" \
  --build-arg TF_SERVING_BUILD_OPTIONS="${TF_SERVING_BUILD_OPTIONS}" \
  -f tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel .
```

Then I run the shell script with >3hrs and get the following failure:
[image]

Actually I cannot know the detail because the log file from docker is clipped by the builder.

Does anyone met the similar problem and can help on this topic?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

These instruction sets are not available on all machines, especially with older processors.

If you'd like to apply generally recommended optimizations, including utilizing platform-specific instruction sets for your processor, you can add ***--config=nativeopt*** to Bazel build commands when building TensorFlow Serving.

`tools/run_in_docker.sh bazel build --config=nativeopt tensorflow_serving/...`